# I have an issue while installing expo-cli using npm

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

C:\Deezer>npm install --global expo-cli
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...dateformat":"3.0.3","'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-09-01T21_24_34_642Z-debug.log

I tried a lot of way to resolve it . I searched in all json files that exist related to it . but nothing happened.

C:\Deezer>npm install --global expo-cli
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...dateformat":"3.0.3","'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-09-01T21_24_34_642Z-debug.log

C:\Deezer>npm install --global expo-cli
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...dateformat":"3.0.3","'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-09-01T21_24_34_642Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, i solved it by switching npm reigistry from the list of given npm registry.

List of Npm registry:

https://registry.npmjs.org/ (Dfault One)

http://r.cnpmjs.org/

https://registry.npm.taobao.org/

https://registry.nodejitsu.com/

http://registry.mirror.cqupt.edu.cn

https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry

https://npm.open-registry.dev/ (https://open-registry.dev)

To switch just type

npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.com/"

Replace the registry url with the above urls check which one works for you.

Then:

npm cache clear --force

solved.

you can then Install