# I got this error "npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nPGP.js v3.0.4\r\nCom'" while trying to install expo-cli

Tags: react-native, expo

I got this error "npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nPGP.js v3.0.4\r\nCom'" while trying to install expo-cli, using npm install expo-cli --global.

I have cleared the cache and tried it many times but the problem persist,

Kindly, let me know if you have had this issue before and how it was rectified

Thank You

Comment: did you try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57749651/i-have-an-issue-while-installing-expo-cli-using-npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to change your registry to avoid this error

here is the list of registries:

- http://r.cnpmjs.org/
- https://registry.npm.taobao.org/
- https://registry.nodejitsu.com/

open Command Prompt as Administrator and paste following commands one by one:

**note:** on URL paste any of above registry.

1. `npm config set registry URL`
2. `npm config list`
   **note:** check the registry URL, is it the as you have change know. if yes then follow net step other try step 1 again
3. `npm cache clear --force`
4. `npm cache verify`

NOW try to install OR create project Hope so its work.

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 0):

step 1)

```
$ npm cache clean --force
```

or

```
$ npm cache verify
```

step 2)

```
$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

or try uninstalling and installing angular/cli

step 3)

```
$ npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

step 4)

delete node_modules and run `$ npm install`